# Yiftach's bones were scattered

Tags: shoftim--book-of, yiftach

I saw in a sefer (Ishei Hatanakh) that Yiftach's bones were scattered as a punishment for killing his daughter. The sefer said the source was otzer midrashim: the aleph bet of ben sira 36, but I cannot find the hebrew text of this online. Does anyone have a link or know where I can find the text for this?
Thank you!

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97_%D7%94%D7%92%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99 חז"ל מותחים ביקורת על יפתח, הן על סיפור המעשה עם בתו, והן על הטבח בבני אפרים. הם מציינים את העובדה כי נקבר בערי גלעד, ומסבירים שאבריו היו נושרים ממנו בחייו ונקברים במקום נפילתם, כעונש על כך שהקריב את בתו ולא התיר את נדרו.

Comment: It's odd that he'd give that as a source, when there are earlier and more reliable midrashim (such as Tanchuma, Parshas Bechukosai) that say the same thing.

Comment: In t'nach we find the punishment for idol worshippers burning of their bones. Similar to the punishment here. Does anyone know why that is considered such a grave punishment and meant to deter them, since they are warned about it. and in the end it did happen to them many years later after their death.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be found on hebrewbooks.

[image]

Comment: Ignore the other highlighted areas ,that occurred due to my poor highlighting skills